# Object data Disappearing

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to make a 20 of my instances which are separated meshes, to look like on in particular (indicated in Red). I'm using ctrl+L to link the object data, but once it's applied, all the instances disappear except for the one (indicated in Red)

[image]

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/167300/something-is-wrong-with-link-object-data-in-blender-2-81

Comment: My guess is they now overlap because they shared the same object origin before linking.

Comment: Hi Lemon, It sort of does the trick, I saw the link, and did the origin to geometry. But all my instances are going right behind the one main object. If they remained in their location it would be a win.

Comment: https://ibb.co/VSCBnyh

They're stacking right behind, all of them.

Comment: Origin to geometry: do it before linking with all objects selected.

Comment: Ok, it worked, but first I had to grab all my instances, go into Tab mode, cursor to selected, which placed it in the middle. The get out of Tab mode, Origin to geometry and then link the object data.